# what is the best from/email validation method in php?

Tags: php, validation, email

I know there is a best method which called "PREG MATCH" in php programming language. I want to know is there any other method in php for validation? and which is the best? what method I practice as a pro php developer? Thank you all :)

Comment: There is no "best". It's always situational.

Comment: The best method, in my opinion, is the one PHP provides you internally. See example #1 of [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/filter_var).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above in the comment, it's situational.

Most of PHP Frameworks have its own validation methods for e-mails and other types of data, yet these methods usually rely on regular expressions ("PREG MATCH") and do additional checks (if the domain has any DNS entry, etc.).

Also, PHP has built-in function `filter_var()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php). It should return `false` if the provided string is not valid e-mail address, but unfortunately it is not always reliable.

You can always use Symfony Validator component without the framework: https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html

Comment: yes I like this Answer. Thank you very much for this information. I don't know about "symfony validator component" before. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot figure out if an email address is valid by looking at its format. If you try, you ***will*** make a mistake that makes it impossible for certain people to register even when using valid email addresses.

It's easy enough to look for addresses of the form `something@example.com` but what about `something.something+else@foo.bar.baz.example.com`? What about `something@example.money` or any newer top-level domain? For every example can list of an unusual address formats, there are a thousand I'm not even thinking of — and neither are you.

You can do a simple check like "does this contain an `@` in it somewhere?" if you want to quickly rule out someone typing their name instead of their email address, or basic "filled in the wrong box" sorts of errors, but don't try to nitpick whether the whole address looks valid.

If you actually need to know if the email address is valid there's one and only one way to do that: send email to it, and have the owner respond (e.g., by clicking a link)